# Extending LVM on virtualized ubuntu server

Tags: linux, docker, storage, lvm, proxmox

Ok, I hope I can explain this correctly. I am running ubuntu server on proxmox. Unbuntu is running my docker instance. My LVM i originally assigned it is full and I added more storage in proxmox thinking it would just expand the LVM, it didn't. I can see the increase in disk size, but I can't figure out how to make the LVM larger.  [fdisk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bPsB.png) [vgdisplay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zr2Cb.png)
As you can /dev/sda has a ton of space that I added in proxmox to that vm. I would like to be to "transfer" that space over to /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv lvm. If anyone has any guidance on how to do it, I would very grateful.

I've tried to follow [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/810221/how-to-correctly-extend-a-linux-device-mapper-partition) guide but ended up corrupting the server and had to restore from backup.

Comment: Add the output of commands as text, not images!

Comment: pvresize, lvresize? That guide is about adding an additional disk, not extending one. Nevertheless this has been described over and over again. If you have trouble with a command post the complete output of the commands you ran.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to correctly 'extend' a linux device mapper partition?](https://serverfault.com/questions/810221/how-to-correctly-extend-a-linux-device-mapper-partition)

Comment: Take a look at the linked question again and only do the commands for expanding your volumes, not creating them.
I have added some additional information as an answer to that question as well, which might help you out.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like /dev/sda already has a configuration and the root file system,including the boot configuration.

You need to move all of that to the lvm, it's a risky operation, but very well described here
https://www.system-rescue.org/lvm-guide-en/Moving-the-linux-rootfs-to-an-LVM-volume/